# How to Read Output From Powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I'm working on making an application to observe servers and monitor CPU/Memory usage using PowerShell.
I'm having trouble with reading the output using C#.

I'm using C# in Visual Studio:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
            psinstance.AddScript("Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName localhost | Select LoadPercentage, CpuStatus | fl");
            var output = psinstance.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject result in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to all of this so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
My intended final result would be written to a variable or file, like:

```
LoadPercentage: xx
CpuStatus : xx
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting from `result`? The [MSDN on PowerShell.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx) has an example that seems to be in line with your intended goal.

Comment: `| fl` -> `| fl | Out-String`